# Google People API gapi.client.people.people.connections.list returns Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-people-api

Google People API gapi.client.people.people.connections.list returns error 403 with error message **Request had insufficient authentication scopes** even though the initialization includes the required scope

```
   gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: '***masked***',
            discoveryDocs: ["https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"],
            clientId: "***masked***.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            'scope': "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"
        });
```

the request looks like this

```
api.client.people.people.connections.list({
        'resourceName': 'people/me',
        'personFields': 'names,emailAddresses'
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.result.emailAddresses[0].value);
        if (importGmailCallback) {
            importGmailCallback(response);
        }
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
    });
```

Waiting for sign in changes happens here

```
Promise.resolve(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()).then(function () {
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(googlePeopleSignedInCallback);
        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        googlePeopleSignedInCallback(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I had a success using similar values in API Explorer, tried to remove access and re-authenticated, deleted all cookies, but no luck

Comment: Are you making sure to wait for the init() response (it's a promise) before making the request? Example: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Comment: Yes, Promise.resolve(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()).then(function () {
  // Listen for sign-in state changes.
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(googlePeopleSignedInCallback);
  // Handle the initial sign-in state.
  googlePeopleSignedInCallback(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
 }, function (error) {
  console.log(error);
 });

Comment: What are the permissions that your application asks for during login?

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly

Comment: I mean on the consent screen that prompts users to allow access to various google services. Generally this screen comes after you've logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the inverted commas in scope.

**Replace:**

'scope':"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"

**with**

scope:"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, looks like I have to use the old API

Comment: Whatever floats your boat ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this scope as well:
"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Did not work, I wish if you could contribute with something you tried or know of